# Data length larger than configured limit with Azure Application Gateway WAF

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

we have the WAF in the Application Gateway configured to "Prevention" mode. A couple of use cases in the application require files to be uploaded. Currently those file upload requests are being blocked by the WAF. Firewall Log:

```
{
...
"properties": {

"requestUri": "/api/v1/attachments",
"ruleSetType": "OWASP",
"ruleSetVersion": "3.0",
"ruleId": "0",
"message": "",
"action": "Blocked",
"site": "Global",
"details": {
  "message": "Request body no files data length is larger than the configured limit (131072).. Deny with code (413)",
  "data": "",
  "file": "",
  "line": ""
},
...
 }
}
```

is it possible to deactivate this rule or change the limit or...?
would scaling up (pricing tier) help?
I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/268d2151-99f3-4eb3-9589-11b26037b034/azure-application-gateway-in-waf-mode-disableincrease-limit-on-secrequestbodylimit-and?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork) but do not want to believe it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Support helped us to resolve the issue.
Specifically these comments helped:

with the proper file-upload field there should be no issue. Here's an example:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"; filename="somefile.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

some jpeg content larger than 128k
```

This could also happen if `"Content-Type: application/json"` or `"Content-Type: text/xml"` is used in the request headers.

Comment: What if the image is a part of a json model?

Comment: Then the WAF should be scanning the entire body to see if there is any attack unless there is a way for the WAF to know that some content is a file and does not need to be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

After several conversations with Microsoft we found that the WAF considers only file attachments if they are sent using multipart/form-data

[image: Multipart example]

If you send it this way the WAF will understand it is a file and thus will apply the limits configured for files instead than for bodies.

There is no other way to send files supported by the WAF for now.